# Failed to convert a wmv file to mp4 with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, wmv, aac

i need a help with this command

**FFMPEG COMMAND:**

```
ffmpeg -y -i /input.wmv -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac -ac 2 -bufsize 20M -sameq -f mp4 /output.mp4
```

**Output:**

```
ffmpeg version 1.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct  9 2012 07:04:08 with gcc 4.4.6 (GCC) 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
[wmv3 @ 0x16a4800] Extra data: 8 bits left, value: 0
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, asf, from '/input.wmv':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKVersion   : 11.0.5721.5275
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    IsVBR           : 0
  Duration: 00:01:35.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 496 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(spa): Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:1(spa): Video: wmv3 (Main) (WMV3 / 0x33564D57), yuv420p, 320x240, 425 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] VBV bufsize set but maxrate unspecified, ignored
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] profile High, level 1.3
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] 264 - core 128 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[wmv3 @ 0x16a4800] Extra data: 8 bits left, value: 0
Output #0, mp4, to '/output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKVersion   : 11.0.5721.5275
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    IsVBR           : 0
    encoder         : Lavf54.29.104
    Stream #0:0(spa): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0:1(spa): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (wmv3 -> libx264)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (wmav2 -> libfaac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libfaac @ 0x16b3600] Que input is backward in time
[mp4 @ 0x16bb3a0] st:0 PTS: 6174 DTS: 6174 < 7169 invalid, clipping
frame=  144 fps=0.0 q=29.0 size=     207kB time=00:00:03.38 bitrate= 500.3kbits/s    
frame=  259 fps=257 q=29.0 size=     447kB time=00:00:07.30 bitrate= 501.3kbits/s    
frame=  375 fps=248 q=29.0 size=     668kB time=00:00:11.01 bitrate= 496.5kbits/s    
frame=  487 fps=241 q=29.0 size=     836kB time=00:00:14.85 bitrate= 460.7kbits/s    
frame=  605 fps=240 q=29.0 size=    1080kB time=00:00:18.92 bitrate= 467.4kbits/s    
frame=  719 fps=238 q=29.0 size=    1306kB time=00:00:22.80 bitrate= 469.2kbits/s    
frame=  834 fps=237 q=29.0 size=    1546kB time=00:00:26.52 bitrate= 477.3kbits/s    
frame=  953 fps=237 q=29.0 size=    1763kB time=00:00:30.27 bitrate= 477.0kbits/s    
frame= 1071 fps=237 q=29.0 size=    1986kB time=00:00:34.36 bitrate= 473.4kbits/s    
frame= 1161 fps=231 q=29.0 size=    2160kB time=00:00:37.21 bitrate= 475.4kbits/s    
frame= 1221 fps=220 q=29.0 size=    2282kB time=00:00:39.53 bitrate= 472.9kbits/s    
frame= 1280 fps=212 q=29.0 size=    2392kB time=00:00:41.16 bitrate= 476.1kbits/s    
frame= 1331 fps=203 q=29.0 size=    2502kB time=00:00:43.23 bitrate= 474.1kbits/s    
frame= 1379 fps=195 q=29.0 size=    2618kB time=00:00:44.72 bitrate= 479.6kbits/s    
frame= 1430 fps=189 q=29.0 size=    2733kB time=00:00:46.34 bitrate= 483.0kbits/s    
frame= 1487 fps=184 q=29.0 size=    2851kB time=00:00:48.40 bitrate= 482.6kbits/s    
frame= 1546 fps=180 q=26.0 size=    2973kB time=00:00:50.43 bitrate= 482.9kbits/s    
frame= 1610 fps=177 q=29.0 size=    3112kB time=00:00:52.40 bitrate= 486.5kbits/s    
frame= 1672 fps=174 q=29.0 size=    3231kB time=00:00:54.35 bitrate= 487.0kbits/s    
frame= 1733 fps=171 q=29.0 size=    3348kB time=00:00:56.51 bitrate= 485.3kbits/s    
frame= 1792 fps=169 q=29.0 size=    3459kB time=00:00:58.28 bitrate= 486.2kbits/s    
frame= 1851 fps=166 q=29.0 size=    3588kB time=00:01:00.32 bitrate= 487.2kbits/s    
frame= 1910 fps=164 q=29.0 size=    3716kB time=00:01:02.36 bitrate= 488.1kbits/s    
frame= 1972 fps=162 q=29.0 size=    3833kB time=00:01:04.45 bitrate= 487.1kbits/s    
frame= 2032 fps=161 q=29.0 size=    3946kB time=00:01:06.40 bitrate= 486.8kbits/s    
frame= 2091 fps=159 q=29.0 size=    4080kB time=00:01:08.35 bitrate= 488.9kbits/s    
frame= 2150 fps=158 q=29.0 size=    4201kB time=00:01:10.54 bitrate= 487.9kbits/s    
frame= 2206 fps=156 q=29.0 size=    4315kB time=00:01:12.39 bitrate= 488.3kbits/s    
frame= 2263 fps=154 q=29.0 size=    4438kB time=00:01:14.21 bitrate= 489.9kbits/s    
frame= 2327 fps=154 q=29.0 size=    4567kB time=00:01:16.16 bitrate= 491.2kbits/s    
frame= 2388 fps=152 q=29.0 size=    4666kB time=00:01:18.48 bitrate= 487.0kbits/s    
frame= 2450 fps=152 q=29.0 size=    4776kB time=00:01:20.24 bitrate= 487.6kbits/s    
frame= 2511 fps=151 q=29.0 size=    4890kB time=00:01:22.15 bitrate= 487.6kbits/s    
frame= 2575 fps=150 q=29.0 size=    5015kB time=00:01:24.42 bitrate= 486.6kbits/s    
frame= 2635 fps=149 q=29.0 size=    5130kB time=00:01:26.62 bitrate= 485.2kbits/s    
frame= 2695 fps=148 q=29.0 size=    5258kB time=00:01:28.65 bitrate= 485.9kbits/s    
frame= 2758 fps=147 q=29.0 size=    5382kB time=00:01:30.64 bitrate= 486.4kbits/s    
frame= 2816 fps=147 q=29.0 size=    5521kB time=00:01:32.69 bitrate= 487.9kbits/s    
get_buffer() failed
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
frame= 2848 fps=143 q=-1.0 Lsize=    5787kB time=00:01:35.10 bitrate= 498.4kbits/s
video:5099kB audio:581kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.884230%
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] frame I:12    Avg QP:22.64  size: 12092
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] frame P:1508  Avg QP:25.39  size:  2933
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] frame B:1328  Avg QP:30.62  size:   491
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] consecutive B-frames: 10.0% 80.8%  8.1%  1.1%
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] mb I  I16..4:  1.8% 72.1% 26.0%
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] mb P  I16..4:  0.4%  2.4%  0.3%  P16..4: 48.3% 19.6% 19.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 9.5%
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.2%  0.0%  B16..8: 52.6%  6.6%  2.3%  direct: 1.4%  skip:36.8%  L0:48.8% L1:42.5% BI: 8.7%
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] 8x8 transform intra:75.3% inter:55.4%
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 77.9% 81.7% 33.1% inter: 24.2% 11.6% 1.1%
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] i16 v,h,dc,p: 25% 16% 44% 14%
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 15% 29%  6%  5%  6%  6%  7%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 20% 15% 17%  7%  9%  8%  9%  7%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] i8c dc,h,v,p: 50% 19% 24%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] Weighted P-Frames: Y:3.8% UV:1.1%
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] ref P L0: 75.6% 19.1%  4.2%  1.0%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] ref B L0: 98.1%  1.9%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] ref B L1: 98.9%  1.1%
[libx264 @ 0x16c3000] kb/s:439.47
```

**FFMPEG Configuration:**

```
--enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvpx --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      51. 73.101 / 51. 73.101
  libavcodec     54. 59.100 / 54. 59.100
  libavformat    54. 29.104 / 54. 29.104
  libavdevice    54.  2.101 / 54.  2.101
  libavfilter     3. 17.100 /  3. 17.100
  libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
```

**PROBLEM #1:**

```
[libfaac @ 0x16b3600] Que input is backward in time
[mp4 @ 0x16bb3a0] st:0 PTS: 6174 DTS: 6174 < 7169 invalid, clipping
```

**PROBLEM #2:**

```
get_buffer() failed
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Please [remove `-sameq`](http://superuser.com/questions/478549/what-is-the-sameq-option-in-ffmpeg-does-it-mean-same-quality), it doesn't make sense. Remove  `-f mp4`, it's redundant. Then, remove `-bufsize 20M` [unless you also specify the VBV's `maxrate`](http://mewiki.project357.com/wiki/X264_Encoding_Suggestions#VBV_Encoding). Generally, if you don't have any quality or bitrate constraints, x264 will assume [CRF](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/werner.robitza/crf.html) 23, which is a sane default value.

Comment: @slhck dont work :S

Comment: Please update your post and include the new commands instead of the old ones. Is there a chance you could upload the sample file for us?

Comment: Probably the same as [FFmpeg Bug #968: Error message at end of asf stream](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/968). Consider providing an additional sample to the bug report and testing git master (the most recent ffmpeg code) if possible. We can help you here if you need instructions.