# LIBFAAC cannot resample channels

Tags: resampling, libav

Im using `avconv` to convert video files into MP4, but whenever I try to encode files with 6 or 8 channels into 2 channels using `libfaac` I get these error messages:

```
Can not resample 8 channels @ 44100 Hz to 2 channels @ 44100 Hz
```

(**EDIT**: the full output of messages can be found here: http://pastebin.com/UXGrBy1D)

These are the codecs we have installed for `avconv`: http://pastebin.com/hyQrqXqW

And this is the command I am running:

```
avconv -y -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -bufsize 20M -maxrate 4000k -threads 12 -same_quant -acodec libfaac -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 128k output.mp4
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Or, is there any alternatives to `libfaac` which *will* resample 8 channels into 2 channels?

I need to be able to do this from a command line on my ubuntu 12.04 server.

Comment: Well, what the error says: It can't automatically downmix the channels. You might need to do it by extracting the original audio, downmix it with `sox` or similar and then multiplex that with the encoded video. Can we see your full, uncut command line output from `avconv`, please?

Comment: Sure, have a look at my edit. The uncut output is pretty big though!

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain what you need to achieve? File size reduction? Compatibility with some device? As for why `-same_quant` shouldn't be used, see: [sameq does not mean "same quality](http://superuser.com/questions/478549/what-is-the-sameq-option-in-ffmpeg-does-it-mean-same-quality).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, if you haven't already done so, check out [this ffmpeg h.264 encoding guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) - it applies to avconv as well, just change every instance of `ffmpeg` to `avconv`. Also, consider upgrading to a more recent version of avconv or ffmpeg - since you're on Ubuntu, you could use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ffmpeg), or [compile it yourself](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide) (this last option will give you access to [fdk_aac](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/AACEncodingGuide), which is a much better AAC encoder than FAAC).

Unless you know exactly what you're doing & have a specific reason, you probably shouldn't use `-bufsize 20M -maxrate 4000k -threads 12 -same_quant`. In fact, going by the input in that pastebin, you should probably just use `-codec:v copy`, which won't touch the video stream.

As for your stated problem... I don't think libfaac is your problem. Look here (from your pastebin):

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from \'/var/www/up/up50eefce404e4f.mp4\':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42
    creation_time   : 2007-12-08 19:28:08
  Duration: 00:46:47.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 308 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 111 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-12-08 19:28:08
    Stream #0.1(und): Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 320x240 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 195 kb/s, 11.99 fps, 11.99 tbr, 11988 tbn, 23976 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-12-08 19:28:11
```

FFmpeg thinks your input audio is stereo. Much later on:

```
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from rate:44100 fmt:s16 ch:2 to rate:44100 fmt:s16 ch:8
Resampling output channel count must be 1 or 2 for mono input; 1, 2 or 6 for stereo input; or N for N channel input.
Can not resample 8 channels @ 44100 Hz to 2 channels @ 44100 Hz
```

The video stream is also throwing up a hell of a lot of errors. I suspect that your input may be corrupted.

It's *possible* that the following command will work:

```
avconv -ac 8 -i input.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a libfaac -b:a 128k -ac 2 output.mp4
```

`-ac` sets the number of audio channels: *if* the AAC stream isn't corrupted, it's possible that the container format is just providing incorrect data to avconv, and putting `-ac 8` before the input overrides the setting provided by the MP4 container (and putting `-ac 2` before the output tells ffmpeg to output to 2 audio channels).