# record application audio only with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, pulse-audio

I would like to use ffmpeg to use application audio only instead of the whole system audio while screen grabbing. How can I do this if the grabbing command is something like this? By application specific I mean it can be audio from chrome(audio is out from chrome through internet)

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s `xdpyinfo | grep 'dimensions:'|awk '{print $2}'` -r 25 -i :0.0 -sameq  desktop.mkv
```

I tried to use pulse audio but I couldn't get it to work.

If someone could even post a link to a working pulse audio setup I would be grateful. I want to do this programatically. And also if I am running two separate audio streams I should be able to capture only one! I was not able to setup that using pavucontrol

Answer (score 2):

First of all don't use [`-sameq`: it does not mean "same quality"](https://superuser.com/a/478550/110524) and has recently been removed from ffmpeg. Instead you can encode a losslessly with libx264:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s $(xdpyinfo | grep 'dimensions:'|awk '{print $2}') -r 25 -i :0.0 -codec:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -qp 0 lossless.mkv
```

Using a lossless encoder is fast; meaning you have a better chance of actually capturing at your declared frame rate. However, the output can be a huge file, so once capturing is completed it is generally re-encoded to a more manageable size:

```
ffmpeg -i lossless.mkv -codec:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

If you computer can handle it you can skip the lossless intermediate step and encode directly to normal, lossy H.264 video.

As for the audio, according to [HOWTO: Proper Screencasting on Linux](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8746719#post8746719):

> Q: How can I control PulseAudio input? (e.g. capture application audio
>   instead of mic)
>
> A: Install “pavucontrol“. Start recording with ffmpeg.
>   Start pavucontrol. Go to the “Recording” tab and you’ll find ffmpeg
>   listed there. Change audio capture from “Internal Audio Analog Stereo”
>   to “Monitor of Internal Audio Analog Stereo“. Now it should record
>   system and application audio instead of microphone.

Your ffmpeg command may then look like:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -f x11grab -r 30 -s 1024x768 -i :0.0 -codec:a pcm_s16le -codec:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -qp 0 output.mkv
```

Also see the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide).

Comment: But I want to do this programatically. And also if I am running two separate audio streams I should be able to capture only one! I was not able to setup that using pavucontrol.

Comment: @PavanK You should have mentioned this in your question.

Comment: I just did thanks for your answer and for your suggestion as well :)