# FFMPEG add keyframes without reencoding

Tags: ffmpeg, flv

How can I add keyframes for FLV files without reencoding? I try to use this command, but do nothing:

```
ffmpeg -i file.flv  -vcodec copy -acodec copy -g 0 -y tmp.flv && yamdi -i tmp.flv -o out.flv
```

The (source and this) result is not seekable corretly with flash player. I have a lot of flv to "repair".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I add keyframes for FLV files without reencoding?

You can't.

A keyframe, or I-frame, is a frame that stands on it's own - it doesn't require any frames before or after in order to be decoded. Other frames are P-frames (which require one or more previous frames to be decoded, and base their contents on changes made to the previous frame rather than forming a complete picture in isolation) and B-frames (the same as P-frames, but reference frames both before *and* after them).

In order to change a P- or B-frame to an I-frame, you need to decode and then re-write the video stream. So you can't add keyframes without re-encoding.

Have a look at the [x264 encoding guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) on the [ffmpeg wiki](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki) for some tips on how to get a good-looking encode.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `-vcodec copy`, you are entirely copying the video codec. Then no parameters can affect the video, so also the GOP size isn't parsed again.

Try just using the gopsize, without a video codec copy:

`ffmpeg -i file.flv -acodec copy -g 1 -sameq -y tmp.flv`

Note the `-sameq` parameter means same quantizer, which should only be used when you are decoding and encoding using the same codec (like MPEG-2 to MPEG-2), like in your case where you don't want to change the codec.

Comment: it's made a bigger file with wrong quality. :( 
so there is no way without reencoding?

Comment: True, the file is bigger, since I-frames are actually JPEG-images (sort of). The other keyframes are predictions to generate a picture, to shrink the filesize. And no, you MUST reencode if you change the GOP-size. If you see quality loss, you must adjust the quality factor. This is the only case where you can use the `-sameq` parameter, because you will use the same codec.

Comment: The reason why this command will give poor results is because of ffmpeg's terrible default settings. If you use `-c:v libx264 -crf 22` or something similar, you'll get a decent-looking picture (see the links in my answer for more information)

Comment: @NickvanTilborg IIRC, newer versions has explicitly disabled `-sameq` since it was mistaken as "same quality". Do you know what the replacement is in newer versions?

Comment: @AlvinWong There is no replacement for `-sameq` because most people abused it, and it never worked properly. See: [What is the “sameq” or “same_quant” option in FFmpeg? Does it mean “same quality”?](http://superuser.com/questions/478549/what-is-the-sameq-or-same-quant-option-in-ffmpeg-does-it-mean-same-quality)