# ffmpeg with 720p video and y4m file

Tags: ffmpeg

I was simulating a lot of videos in cif format, also all videos came with yuv format file.
I used the expression below and it works well:

```
ffmpeg -s cif -r 30 -i video.yuv -vcodec mpeg4 -g 12 -bf 2 -sameq video.m4v
```

But now I'm looking for simulations with HD videos and they come with y4m extensions. Do you know witch expression I should use?

I tried to replace `-s hd720`, instead of `-s cif` and still not working:

```
ffmpeg -s hd720 -i ducks_take_off_420_720p50.y4m -vcodec mpeg4 -g 12 -bf 2 -sameq video.m4v
```

Error: `Option video_size not found`

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to declare an input `-s` or `-r` for y4m ([YUV4MPEG2](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=YUV4MPEG2)). It contains a header with the frame width, frame height, and frame rate, among other information that may be present.

Also, [`-sameq` does not mean "same quality"](https://superuser.com/a/478550/110524) and has been removed from ffmpeg. You can use `-qscale:v` instead when using the encoder `mpeg4`. A sane value is 2-5, and a lower value is a higher quality. 2 is roughly visually lossless.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to `scale` the input video the the `-s` tag should come AFTER the `-i`

The following should work (with updated syntax):

`ffmpeg -i ducks_take_off_420_720p50.y4m -s hd720 -c:v mpeg4 -g 12 -bf 2 -q:v 0 video.m4v`

If you are not willing to scale the video, you should not include the `-s` tag at all and make sure that the input video is an `hd720` video.