# Concat 2 .mp4 files created with ffmpeg not working correctly

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to concat 2 mp4 files that were both created with ffmpeg however the resulting output file does not contain any audio, can someone please help?

Here's my current code:

```
function appendVideo($input, $input_second, $outputfolder, $outputname) {
    // output
    $output = $outputfolder . $outputname;
    // intermediate
    $randomString1 = substr( "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", mt_rand(0, 50) , 1) .substr( md5( time() ), 1);
    $randomString2 = substr( "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", mt_rand(0, 50) , 1) .substr( md5( time() ), 1);
    $intermediate1 = $outputfolder . "i1_".$randomString1.".mpg";
    $intermediate2 = $outputfolder . "i2_".$randomString2.".mpg";
    //convert to mpg

    $exec1 = "ffmpeg -i $input -sameq $intermediate1 2>&1";
    $exec2 = "ffmpeg -i $input_second -sameq $intermediate2 2>&1";

    exec($exec1,$results1,$return1);
    exec($exec2,$results2,$return2);


    // join and convert back
    $exec = "cat $intermediate1 $intermediate2 | ffmpeg -i - -codec:a copy $output 2>&1";
    //delete the intermediate files


    exec ($exec,$results,$return);

        if (file_exists ( $intermediate1 )) {
        unlink ( $intermediate1 );
    }
    if (file_exists ( $intermediate2 )) {
        unlink ( $intermediate2 );
    }

    return $results;

}
```

And this is the result returned from ffmpeg in case it helps:

```
ffmpeg version 0.10.9 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Oct 1 2013 19:47:54 with gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libcelt --enable-libdc1394 --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
libavutil 51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100
libavcodec 53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100
libavformat 53. 32.100 / 53. 32.100
libavdevice 53. 4.100 / 53. 4.100
libavfilter 2. 61.100 / 2. 61.100
libswscale 2. 1.100 / 2. 1.100
libswresample 0. 6.100 / 0. 6.100
libpostproc 52. 0.100 / 52. 0.100
mpeg @ 0x111afc0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
nput #0, mpeg, from 'pipe:':
Duration: N/A, start: 1.000000, bitrate: 104985 kb/s
Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p, 768x432 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 104857 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
buffer @ 0x1137280] w:768 h:432 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/1000000 sar:1/1 sws_param:
libx264 @ 0x11221e0] using SAR=1/1
libx264 @ 0x11221e0] using cpu capabilities: none!
libx264 @ 0x11221e0] profile High, level 3.0
libx264 @ 0x11221e0] 264 - core 120 r2151 a3f4407 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2011 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
utput #0, mp4, to 'tmp/zdee7489be42d6db4bfe9ce8e67da161.mp4':
Metadata:
encoder : Lavf53.32.100
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (![0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 768x432 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2 (i[0][0][0] / 0x0069), 44100 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg1video -> libx264)
    Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
frame= 46 fps= 0 q=0.0 size= 0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate= 0.0kbits/s 
frame= 66 fps= 60 q=29.0 size= 135kB time=00:00:00.26 bitrate=4141.1kbits/s 
frame= 79 fps= 49 q=29.0 size= 257kB time=00:00:00.70 bitrate=3011.9kbits/s 
frame= 93 fps= 44 q=29.0 size= 386kB time=00:00:01.16 bitrate=2711.4kbits/s 
...
frame= 105 fps= 39 q=29.0 size= 487kideo:14440kB audio:3140kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.021247%
[libx264 @ 0x11221e0] frame I:31 Avg QP:18.84 size: 42581
[libx264 @ 0x11221e0] frame P:3369 Avg QP:21.98 size: 3277
[libx264 @ 0x11221e0] frame B:2629 Avg QP:27.40 size: 923
[libx264 @ 0x11221e0] consecutive B-frames: 37.1% 14.2% 0.5% 48.2%
[libx264 @ 0x11221e0] mb I I16..4: 7.6% 68.7% 23.6%
[libx264 @ 0x11221e0] mb P I16..4: 0.6% 1.5% 0.2% P16..4: 20.9% 7.1% 5.3% 0.0% 0.0% skip:64.3%
[libx264 @ 0x11221e0] mb B I16..4: 0.1% 0.1% 0.0% B16..8: 17.2% 3.2% 1.0% direct: 0.7% skip:77.6% L0:39.4% L1:51.8% BI: 8.8%
[libx264 @ 0x11221e0] 8x8 transform intra:64.8% inter:69.2%
[libx264 @ 0x11221e0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 57.6% 72.7% 35.5% inter: 7.6% 11.8% 0.6%
[libx264 @ 0x11221e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 41% 21% 16% 21%
[libx264 @ 0x11221e0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 21% 30% 5% 3% 3% 5% 4% 7%
[libx264 @ 0x11221e0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 31% 23% 12% 4% 5% 5% 7% 6% 6%
[libx264 @ 0x11221e0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 44% 24% 25% 7%
[libx264 @ 0x11221e0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.7% UV:0.5%
[libx264 @ 0x11221e0] ref P L0: 69.8% 12.5% 10.8% 6.8% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x11221e0] ref B L0: 89.9% 8.5% 1.6%
[libx264 @ 0x11221e0] ref B L1: 97.2% 2.8%
[libx264 @ 0x11221e0] kb/s:588.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess here as to what you're trying to achieve, but the immediate solution to your problem would be to use `-c:a aac -strict experimental` instead of `-codec:a copy`. Your .mpg files use the `mp2` audio codec which is apparently not supported in an MP4 container.

But then again, there are quite a few things wrong here. By converting to `.mpg` without any additional options you're creating MPEG-1 video, which either results in horrible quality, or terribly huge files. Also, [`-sameq` doesn't do what you expect it to do](https://superuser.com/questions/478549/what-is-the-sameq-or-same-quant-option-in-ffmpeg-does-it-mean-same-quality). Please forget that option. Lastly, the double conversion introduces quality loss.

First, update to a [recent version of `ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html). Then, read the guide at [How to concatenate (join, merge) media files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files), especially the part about the `concat` filter. There you could concatenate two files directly without needing intermediates.

Comment: Thanks a lot slhck! Here's a bit more information. I am creating a software that takes an mp4 file from youtube (which my software grabs), and adds in an intro and or outro to the video which are created by my users through the software. The intro, outro and youtube videos are all encoded using ffmpeg.  And YES, when this DOES work, the file it generates is HUGE. I'll definitely upgrade my version of ffmpeg.

Comment: Alright skhck, quick update...what you suggested with using -c:a aac -strict experimental actually WORKED and the output video now contains both audios :) So THANK YOU for that! I don't suppose you would be willing to tell me how to fade out my intro video and fade in the next video would ya?

Comment: Hey everyone I updated my version of ffmpeg to the most recent and the videos are joining okay however the major issue now is that the audio and video are out of sync...Any other help available here on this issue?

Comment: Hi @Jeff! I'd suggest you post a new question for the sync error you receive, and include the actual command and command line output. As for your `var_dump()`, you might be able to split it via `explode()` into newlines.

Comment: here's my post with the out of sync question. Please see if you are able to help me, I've been up for almost 60 hours straight my friend and am about to lose it over here lol thanks! http://superuser.com/questions/697492/ffmpeg-audio-and-video-out-of-sync

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg can use more than one input file to generate an output file.  Maybe try the -concat option instead of using 'cat' to combine them.

documentation on that:
http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files

Also, version 2.1 is the latest release:

- http://www.ffmpeg.org
- http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: @slhck beat me to the concat option.  Yeah, and I didn't even notice the incongruity with the audio vs container.  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I upgraded to ffmpeg-3.0 following all instruction on following page.

http://ask.xmodulo.com/compile-ffmpeg-centos-fedora-rhel.html

compilation took 10 minutes and I got error for not able to open libavdevice.so.57 which I resolved from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901706/ffmpeg-error-in-linux.
It worked fine. I could join multiple mp4 videos together using 
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy Final_Video.mp4

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.